# Get Query Binding array result in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to prevent injection on my codeigniter script. I used Query Binding array, but It's not fetching out the result... I get this error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs

code bellow

```
<php
$my = "Select * from gw_marge where amount != ? AND is_activated= ? ORDER BY RAND()";
$this->db->query($my, array(0, 1));
      foreach ($my->result() as $roww)
    {
    $pay = $roww->amount;
    $idd = $roww->id;
  }
 ?>
<p><?php echo $pay.' &'.$idd; ?></p>
```

Where did i get it wrong.

Comment: is this solved ??

Comment: Not solved yet... i get error. _Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs_

Comment: Is this code in Model or controller ??

Comment: I have it in view

Comment: its wrong then. Add your controller as well

Comment: @AbdullaNilam how?... you want me to put it into controller instead of view?

Comment: View is just to show. Controller call it and Model process it. MVC is that. [READ THIS](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/overview/mvc.html). What you doing is just and Pure PHP. Nothing to do with codeigniter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$this->db->query($my, array(0, 1));
foreach ($my->result() as $roww)
```

to

```
$query = $this->db->query($my, array(0, 1));
foreach ($query->result() as $roww)
```

Comment: without giving(***wrong***) solution it's better to tell him why we use **MVC**. [check this comment as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43100209/get-query-binding-array-result-in-codeigniter?noredirect=1#comment73283534_43100209)

Comment: @AbdullaNilam, You are correct that his approach is not good MVC. But the question was "why do I get this error" and not "what's wrong with my MVC use." But the real reason I did not comment on MVC is that it wasn't known that his code was in the view until after I posted the answer. You've got the reputation to edit my answer - go ahead and explain the proper MVC structure. (I would, but must go back to work)